# Get only href content and src content from html

Tags: java, android, regex

I am wondering how to extract only `href` and `src` content from html content.
I tried regular expression but I failed.

This is the text that I want to get `href` and `src` content from:

```
<a href="http://rdmobile.fr/blog/mobile-la-pub-consomme-plus-que-les-applications-elles-memes/"><img align="left" hspace="5" width="150" height="150" src="http://rdmobile.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/angry-birds-150x150.jpg" class="alignleft tfe wp-post-image" alt="angry-birds" title="angry-birds" /></a>Si vous aussi vous vous étonnez de voir votre batterie fondre comme neige au soleil dès lors que jouez à Angry Birds, rassurez-vous, c’est normal. Des chercheurs de l&#8217;université de Purdue se sont intéressés aux publicités destinées majoritairement aux applications gratuites, et oui, comment les développeurs mangent-ils autrement ? Plus sérieusement, cette étude, publiée sur le [...]
```

I want to extract data like this.

href content :http://rdmobile.fr/blog/mobile-la-pub-consomme-plus-que-les-applications-elles-memes/
src content : http://rdmobile.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/angry-birds-150x150.jpg

Can any one help me with this and I like to learn basic regular expression too.

Thanks,
Isuru

Comment: Don't use regex, use DOM

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Extracting data from html using regular expressions is not generally recommended, but the following is an example of one basic approach

```
String str = "<a href=\"http://rdmobile.fr/blog/mobile-la-pub-consomme-plus-que-les-applications-elles-memes/\"><img align=\"left\" hspace=\"5\" width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"http://rdmobile.fr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/angry-birds-150x150.jpg\" class=\"alignleft tfe wp-post-image\" alt=\"angry-birds\" title=\"angry-birds\" /></a>Si vous aussi vous vous étonnez de voir votre batterie fondre comme neige au soleil dès lors que jouez à Angry Birds, rassurez-vous, c’est normal. Des chercheurs de l&#8217;université de Purdue se sont intéressés aux publicités destinées majoritairement aux applications gratuites, et oui, comment les développeurs mangent-ils autrement ? Plus sérieusement, cette étude, publiée sur le [...]";        
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(" (?:href|src)=\"([^\"]+)").matcher(str);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The above will only match any sequence of one or more characters that are not `"`, when it is preceded by either `' href="'` or `' src="'`.

Therefore it will not match if single or no quotes surround the attribute value or if there are any spaces around the `=`.

Further explanation on request, or see, for example, [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

A DOM parser like **[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)** is great for this type of problem, and allows for straight-forward interactions with the document & using CSS style selectors:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements elementsWithSrcAttributes = document.select("[src]");
Elements elementsWithHrefAttributes = document.select("[href]");

for (Element element: elementsWithSrcAttributes) {
    System.out.println("src content: " + element.attr("src"));
}

for (Element element: elementsWithHrefAttributes) {
    System.out.println("href content: " + element.attr("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the content using an XML parser.

Look at [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use regular expressions for that. Just... just don't. [Bad things happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

What you want to use is [XPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html). For a given HTML document, the `/a/@href` XPath expression will return all `href` attributes of `a` nodes. Think of it as regular expressions for XML.

The hard part isn't XPath, which is relatively straightforward, but obtaining a valid DOM from an HTML file. I'd recommend [Cyberneko](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml/), but have no idea whether that's compatible with your Android requirement.